# JPA Typed query set parameter

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a named parameter in `JPA` typed query. I am setting a list of value in condition.

I am setting a list of integer, but when `JPA` converts typed query to corresponding sql query it is adding a to_number function and index of the table is not used.

```
 List<Integer> studentIds=ArrayList<Integer>
 //Student id is number in database and indexed.     
 query = "SELECT T.* FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENT_ID IN (:studentIds)" 
 TypedQuery<Object[]> typedQuery = entityManager().createQuery( query, Object[].class);
 typedQuery.setParameter("studentIds", studentIds);
```

The issue is when JPA generates the query it is adding to_number function to convert the list

```
SELECT * from student t4 where student_id in (?,?,?);
 filter("T4"."student_id"=TO_NUMBER(:9) OR "T4"."student_id"=TO_NUMBER(:10) OR 
  "T4"."student_id"=TO_NUMBER(:11) OR "T4"."PRODUCT_SET_ID"=student_id(:12)
```

Any thoughts how to make sure JPA does not add a to_number function, so index will be used.

Comment: First of all any function over a *constant* is no harm. Only when applied over an indexed column the index will not be used.

Comment: Yes the issue is index is not used and query is running long.

Comment: Did you try with only one value in you IN list?

Answer (score 2):

I had to use an array when I was passing values into a '.in' predicate. Try this:

```
List<Integer> studentIds=ArrayList<Integer>
Integer[] ids = new Integer[studentIds.size()];
ids = studentIds.toArray(ids);
//Student id is number in database and indexed.     
query = "SELECT T.* FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENT_ID IN (:studentIds)"
TypedQuery<Object[]> typedQuery = entityManager().createQuery( query, Object[].class);
typedQuery.setParameter("studentIds", ids);
```